# Array Element to Array Element Copy in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to Excel VBA and I came from a SAS programming background meaning I didn't utilize a lot of arrays and thus have hardly any experience with it. So please, forgive me if I get any of the terminologies wrong.

I have 2 dynamic arrays and want to create a 3rd one based off these two and they each will have the same # of elements and will be all 1 dimensional. Array1 will have all elements filled - however Array2 will have some elements filled but are mostly blank for our purposes now. Whenever Array2 has an element filled, it will replace whatever Element number on Array1 for Array3.

I made a screenshot for a visualization for what I'm looking for.

[image: PIC]

Any help or possible functions where I can look more into it would be helpful!

Comment: Sounds like a simple loop with an if statement controlling which array is used to populate the destination array  Some related info from microsoft: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213798

Comment: Make sure you embed the pictures and not link them (if you have privileges). I have edited your post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

So you want this:

[image: P1] --> [image: P2]

I used this code:

```
Public Sub ProcessArrays()

    Dim x1() As Variant, x2() As Variant, x3() As Variant
    Dim i As Integer, N As Integer
    ' Count non-empty cells
    N = CountRows(Range("A2"))
    ' Read array1 and array2
    x1 = Range("A2").Resize(N, 1).Value
    x2 = Range("B2").Resize(N, 1).Value
    ' Declare array3
    ReDim x3(1 To N, 1 To 1)

    'Process arrays
    For i = 1 To N
        If Not IsEmpty(x2(i, 1)) Then
            x3(i, 1) = x2(i, 1)
        Else
            x3(i, 1) = x1(i, 1)
        End If
    Next i

    'Output array 3
    Range("C2").Resize(N, 1).Value = x3

End Sub


Public Function CountRows(ByRef r As Range) As Long
    If IsEmpty(r) Then
        CountRows = 0
    ElseIf IsEmpty(r.Offset(1, 0)) Then
        CountRows = 1
    Else
        CountRows = r.Worksheet.Range(r, r.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Make `Array1`,`Array2` equal sized using `ReDim`  and `Preserve`

2.Declare `Array3` of size: `Max(size of Array1,size of Array2)`

3.Check for `IsMissing` or `IsEmpty` values from Array2 and Merge

```
Sub MyMerger()
Dim Array1, Array2
Array1 = Array(5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11)    
Array2 = Array(, , 9, , , 2)    

ReDim Preserve Array2(UBound(Array1))    
ReDim Array3(WorksheetFunction.Max(UBound(Array1), UBound(Array2)))    

For i = 0 To UBound(Array3)
    If Not (IsMissing(Array2(i)) Or IsEmpty(Array2(i))) Then
    Array3(i) = Array2(i)
    Else
    Array3(i) = Array1(i)

    End If
Next i
End Sub
```