# Excel: Help converting a working formula into VBA/Macro

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

so I am trying to write a formula that allows me to copy a certain value that is on sheet 2 onto sheet 1 if and only if it exists by the column "Num Available"

```
Sheet 2/Line 1:
   B           C
PRODUCT "NUM AVAILABLE"
   A           12
   B           
   C           15
   D           13
   E
Sheet 1:

RUN 1
PRODUCT "NUM AVAILABLE"
  A          12

RUN 2
PRODUCT "NUM AVAILABLE"
  C          15

RUN 3
PRODUCT "NUM AVAILABLE"
 D           13
```

The formula I am using is for Run 1 is:

`=IF('Line 1'!C5>0,'Line 1'!$B5,IF('Line 1'!C6>0,'Line 1'!$B6,IF('Line 1'!C7>0,'Line 1'!$B7,IF('Line 1'!C8>0,'Line 1'!$B8,IF('Line 1'!C9>0,'Line 1'!$B9,IF('Line 1'!C10>0,'Line 1'!$B10,IF('Line 1'!C11>0,'Line 1'!$B11,IF('Line 1'!C12>0,'Line 1'!$B12,IF('Line 1'!C13>0,'Line 1'!$B13,IF('Line 1'!C14>0,'Line 1'!$B14,IF('Line 1'!C15>0,'Line 1'!$B15,IF('Line 1'!C16>0,'Line 1'!$B16,IF('Line 1'!C17>0,'Line 1'!$B17,IF('Line 1'!C18>0,'Line 1'!$B18,IF('Line 1'!C19>0,'Line 1'!$B19,IF('Line 1'!C20>0,'Line 1'!$B20,IF('Line 1'!C21>0,'Line 1'!$B21,IF('Line 1'!C22>0,'Line 1'!$B22,IF('Line 1'!C23>0,'Line 1'!$B23,IF('Line 1'!C24>0,'Line 1'!$B24,IF('Line 1'!C25>0,'Line 1'!$B25,IF('Line 1'!C26>0,'Line 1'!$B26,IF('Line 1'!C27>0,'Line 1'!$B27, "NO ENTRY")))))))))))))))))))))))`

Lines are the same thing as Sheets.

My problem is that this code eventually becomes massive when I use this on other Lines and increase the number of runs i'm looking at. This code prints out a product name for Run 2 if it exists in "Number available" and does not exists in Run 1

```
Run 2:
```

`=IF(AND(NOT(D$5='Line 1'!$B5),'Line 1'!C5>0),'Line 1'!$B5,IF(AND(NOT(D$5='Line 1'!$B6),'Line 1'!C6>0),'Line 1'!$B6,IF(AND(NOT(D$5='Line 1'!$B7),'Line 1'!C7>0),'Line 1'!$B7,IF(AND(NOT(D$5='Line 1'!$B8),'Line 1'!C8>0),'Line 1'!$B8,IF(AND(NOT(D$5='Line 1'!$B9),'Line 1'!C9>0),'Line 1'!$B9,IF(AND(NOT(D$5='Line 1'!$B10),'Line 1'!C10>0),'Line 1'!$B10,IF(AND(NOT(D$5='Line 1'!$B11),'Line 1'!C11>0),'Line 1'!$B11,IF(AND(NOT(D$5='Line 1'!$B12),'Line 1'!C12>0),'Line 1'!$B12,IF(AND(NOT(D$5='Line 1'!$B13),'Line 1'!C13>0),'Line 1'!$B13,IF(AND(NOT(D$5='Line 1'!$B14),'Line 1'!C14>0),'Line 1'!$B14,IF(AND(NOT(D$5='Line 1'!$B15),'Line 1'!C15>0),'Line 1'!$B15,IF(AND(NOT(D$5='Line 1'!$B16),'Line 1'!C16>0),'Line 1'!$B16,IF(AND(NOT(D$5='Line 1'!$B17),'Line 1'!C17>0),'Line 1'!$B17,IF(AND(NOT(D$5='Line 1'!$B18),'Line 1'!C18>0),'Line 1'!$B18,IF(AND(NOT(D$5='Line 1'!$B19),'Line 1'!C19>0),'Line 1'!$B19,IF(AND(NOT(D$5='Line 1'!$B20),'Line 1'!C20>0),'Line 1'!$B20,IF(AND(NOT(D$5='Line 1'!$B21),'Line 1'!C21>0),'Line 1'!$B21,IF(AND(NOT(D$5='Line 1'!$B22),'Line 1'!C22>0),'Line 1'!$B22,IF(AND(NOT(D$5='Line 1'!$B23),'Line 1'!C23>0),'Line 1'!$B23,IF(AND(NOT(D$5='Line 1'!$B24),'Line 1'!C24>0),'Line 1'!$B24,IF(AND(NOT(D$5='Line 1'!$B25),'Line 1'!C25>0),'Line 1'!$B25,IF(AND(NOT(D$5='Line 1'!$B26),'Line 1'!C26>0),'Line 1'!$B26,IF(AND(NOT(D$5='Line 1'!$B27),'Line 1'!C27>0),'Line 1'!$B27,IF(AND(NOT(D$5='Line 1'!$B28),'Line 1'!C28>0),'Line 1'!$B28,IF(AND(NOT(D$5='Line 1'!$B29),'Line 1'!C29>0),'Line 1'!$B29,IF(AND(NOT(D$5='Line 1'!$B30),'Line 1'!C30>0),'Line 1'!$B30,IF(AND(NOT(D$5='Line 1'!$B31),'Line 1'!C31>0),'Line 1'!$B31, "NO ENTRY")))))))))))))))))))))))))))`

When I increase the number of Runss to 5, I exceed the number of characters I can use. I do need some help on this. The formula does exactly what I need--I just need a more effective way to accomplish my goal. VBA or formula simplification advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Woah my eyes are burning! I can't read that. Do some research on SELECT CASE in VBA. Have a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx

Comment: There are many ways you could accomplish this, but they all would include the use of a loop. So I'd suggest starting by learning about loops. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221353(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: If it requires more than two nested `IF()` statements, you are doing it wrong. Ok, maybe 3 sometimes, but that's it.

Comment: I appreciate all of the help! As I said before, I'm new to VBA. The formula does accomplish what I need--I just need a better solution.

@pnuts The pivot table function will not accomplish what I need as there are many sheets that I am compiling into the summary sheet. Maybe my knowledge of pivot table is limited.

Comment: @RossMcConeghy I figure loops are the way to solve this. Any chance you could give out some ways to solve my problem? As you said, there are many ways and what you know probably exceeds what I know. Clearly I used an inefficient method, so maybe by listing different ways of accomplishing what I would like to do, it could spark some nice conversation with other members of StackOverflow.

Comment: @Gareth Thanks for the comment, I will do some research on SELECT CASE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could also be achieved with a matrix formula.

In Sheet1 B2:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!B$2:B$10000,SMALL(IF(Sheet2!$C$2:$C$10000>0,ROW(Sheet2!$C$2:$C$10000)-1),ROW(A1)))
```

Paste the formula into the cell and then press [ctrl]+[shift]+[enter] to create a matrix formula. Then it looks like:

```
{=INDEX(Sheet2!B$2:B$10000,SMALL(IF(Sheet2!$C$2:$C$10000>0,ROW(Sheet2!$C$2:$C$10000)-1),ROW(A1)))}
```

Now you can copy this formula downwards and to right.

Greetings

Axel

Comment: You are the man! Your solution was easy to translate over to my needs plus no VBA was involved! This solution is exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25385506/380384) and adapt it to your needs.

The core reads values into arrays as needed, loops through to create an output array and then writes the results out in one operation.

```
x1 = Range("A2").Resize(N, 1).Value
x2 = Range("B2").Resize(N, 1).Value
' Declare array3
ReDim x3(1 To N, 1 To 1)

'Process arrays
For i = 1 To N
    If Not IsEmpty(x2(i, 1)) Then
        x3(i, 1) = x2(i, 1)
    Else
        x3(i, 1) = x1(i, 1)
    End If
Next i

'Output array 3
Range("C2").Resize(N, 1).Value = x3
```

I cannot tell much from the given information (maybe screen shots can help) so this is the best I can do now. Maybe you need two loops, creating a new worksheet on the outer loop and copying values in the inner loop.